# How to wire an always on, power interrupting light switch?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, fans

I have a moisture sensing fan in my bathrooms that behave as follows...

- Turned on, shows blue light, fan will turn on / off automatically based on moisture sensor
- Turned off, shows no light, fan always off
- Turned on, shows red light, fan always on
- Etc. The fan will switch back and forth

...I'd like the mode light to always be on, to make the experience nicer by removing the completely off state and either have the fan in the moisture sensing mode or full on mode. It's pretty annoying to have to turn the switch on and off multiple times to get it in the right state.

So the fan needs to always have power and my switch needs to temporarily stop the power in order to toggle the modes. Ideally I'd like the solution to use my standard paddle switches.

I appreciate any thoughts on how I can make this happen.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to leave the switch on all the time. You could just pull the switch out of the wall box and turn it over so "on" is down.

Comment: Can you post a make/model and/or install instructions for your fan?

Comment: That trick with turning the light switch off and on to change modes, is a **feature** they spent a lot of time and money to add to the fan.  It's specifically designed to work well in the difficult situation where you can't wire /3 cable to the fan.  Perhaps with that level of forethought, they have found a way to also let you wire it with /3.  Or perhaps they simply mean for you to buy a different product at that point.  The manual will tell the tale.  *It goes without saying you will need /3 (or an extra hot wire) in your cable.  If you don't have that, this won't happen.*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel please see the manual here... http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/b3/b3188a29-f76e-41af-a327-71b2db1d1227.pdf

Comment: Is getting a different fan an option? Or are you stuck with this particular fan?

Comment: Already installed :/ but I do have 2 hot wires going to the unit as it used to be a heat lamp fan combo before, if that helps.